# Integration of dreamweaver and php

Tags: php, dreamweaver

Its my first project with PHP, I am still learning phase. Designer is working on dreamweaver to design the web site. As I developer I only understand code and feel comfortable with working on eclipse.

How can we integrate the project, that we both are looking at the same file but with different software/IDE.

Secondly , I will be using XAMPP for Windows but I am confused how the designer will use apache.

All I am looking for what to tools and practices are used when Dev's are working eclipse and designer are working Dreamweaver ?

Comment: I see it marked for close. All i want to know how the designer and users manage php projects.

Comment: It shouldn't matter what IDEs you use as long as you are using a revision control system such as SVN or GIT.  Also, XAMPP is apache (or rather includes it), so there's no issue there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should keep you code separated from the html in different files. have you looked into mvc architecture?

if you use an mvc architecture or similar separation of html and php source files, you guys should never really be working on the same files anyways.

if you choose not to, set up an svn (subversion) server so that you guys can work on your project independently of one another but stay in sync. it shouldn't matter what ide anyone uses. dreamweaver has functionality to use subversion for source control, test and production server setup for easy sets/gets. you basically set it up the same as an ftp.